# Elasticsearch timing out on index.exists / HEAD requests

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-swarm

I'm having a weird issue with ES 5.6.5 in a Docker container in swarm mode. Here's the code in question:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from settings import ES_HOSTS

db = Elasticsearch(hosts=ES_HOSTS)
db.indices.exists(index=product_id)
```

It performs an HTTP HEAD request in the background and that request times out, never getting a response. I confirmed by doing the same HEAD request using curl (`curl -X HEAD http://elasticsearch:9200/85a9b708-e89d-11e7-887a-02420aff0008`) and it does indeed time out. Other requests work just fine. For example, if I do a GET request to the aforementioned URL, I get the expected error saying the index does not exist.

When I run the same ES image on a standalone docker container on my machine, configured exactly the same way and with the same code making the calls, it works without a problem.

Here's the relevant swarm configuration section:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.5"
  environment:
    - cluster.name=raul_elasticsearch
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  volumes:
    - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
  deploy:
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 6G
      reservations:
        memory: 6G
```

And this is the command I ran for having a standalone ES docker container:

`docker run --rm -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -d --name raul_elasticsearch docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.5`

Any thoughts on what could be causing the issue?

UPDATE1: looking at the debug logs from the ES running in the docker swarm, I am getting the following messages:

```
Dec 24 17:10:33:  [2017-12-24T17:10:33,839][DEBUG][r.suppressed             ] path: /85a9b708-e89d-11e7-887a-02420aff0008, params: {index=85a9b708-e89d-11e7-887a-02420aff0008} 
Dec 24 17:10:33:  org.elasticsearch.index.IndexNotFoundException: no such index 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.infe(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:676) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.innerResolve(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:630) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.resolve(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:578) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndices(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:168) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndexNames(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:144) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndexNames(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:77) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.TransportGetIndexAction.checkBlock(TransportGetIndexAction.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.TransportGetIndexAction.checkBlock(TransportGetIndexAction.java:47) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.doStart(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.start(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:104) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:142) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:83) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:72) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1256) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.getIndex(AbstractClient.java:1357) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.admin.indices.RestGetIndicesAction.lambda$prepareRequest$0(RestGetIndicesAction.java:97) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:80) [elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:262) [elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:200) [elasticsearch-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(Netty4HttpServerTransport.java:505) [transport-netty4-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:80) [transport-netty4-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:68) [transport-netty4-5.6.5.jar:5.6.5] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284) [netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:544) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458) [netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar:4.1.13.Final] 
Dec 24 17:10:33:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
```

Additionally, I also get these messages, most of which seem to be related to a periodic task, but one caught my eye: `Can not start an object, expecting field name (context: Object)`

```
Dec 24 17:10:36: [2017-12-24T17:10:36,919][DEBUG][o.e.x.m.a.GetDatafeedsStatsAction$TransportAction] [hPjV7-n] Get stats for datafeed '_all' 
Dec 24 17:10:36: [2017-12-24T17:10:36,923][DEBUG][o.e.x.m.e.l.LocalExporter] monitoring index templates and pipelines are installed on master node, service can start 
Dec 24 17:10:46: [2017-12-24T17:10:46,932][DEBUG][o.e.x.m.a.GetDatafeedsStatsAction$TransportAction] [hPjV7-n] Get stats for datafeed '_all' 
Dec 24 17:10:46: [2017-12-24T17:10:46,935][DEBUG][o.e.x.m.e.l.LocalExporter] monitoring index templates and pipelines are installed on master node, service can start 
Dec 24 17:10:56: [2017-12-24T17:10:56,920][DEBUG][o.e.x.m.a.GetDatafeedsStatsAction$TransportAction] [hPjV7-n] Get stats for datafeed '_all' 
Dec 24 17:10:56: [2017-12-24T17:10:56,927][DEBUG][o.e.x.m.e.l.LocalExporter] monitoring index templates and pipelines are installed on master node, service can start 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,707][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.e.ExecutionService] [hPjV7-n] saving watch records [4] 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,711][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.e.ExecutionService] [hPjV7-n] executing watch [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_kibana_version_mismatch] 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,711][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.e.ExecutionService] [hPjV7-n] executing watch [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_elasticsearch_cluster_status] 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,711][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_kibana_version_mismatch_4e9bb936-dc65-4795-8be3-b2b2c1660460-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] found [0] hits 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,711][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.e.ExecutionService] [hPjV7-n] executing watch [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_elasticsearch_version_mismatch] 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,712][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_kibana_version_mismatch_4e9bb936-dc65-4795-8be3-b2b2c1660460-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] found [0] hits 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,713][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_elasticsearch_version_mismatch_0a13442f-96dc-4732-b0de-1e87a9dc05ab-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] found [0] hits 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,714][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_elasticsearch_version_mismatch_0a13442f-96dc-4732-b0de-1e87a9dc05ab-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] found [0] hits 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,714][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_elasticsearch_cluster_status_b35f5be6-4d4b-4fa2-a50c-6f18d4b6d949-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] found [15178] hits 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,715][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_elasticsearch_cluster_status_b35f5be6-4d4b-4fa2-a50c-6f18d4b6d949-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] hit [{ 
Dec 24 17:10:58:   "error" : "Can not start an object, expecting field name (context: Object)" 
Dec 24 17:10:58: }] 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,716][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_elasticsearch_cluster_status_b35f5be6-4d4b-4fa2-a50c-6f18d4b6d949-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] found [1] hits 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,716][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_elasticsearch_cluster_status_b35f5be6-4d4b-4fa2-a50c-6f18d4b6d949-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] hit [{ 
Dec 24 17:10:58:   "error" : "Can not start an object, expecting field name (context: Object)" 
Dec 24 17:10:58: }] 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,718][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.e.ExecutionService] [hPjV7-n] executing watch [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_logstash_version_mismatch] 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,718][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_logstash_version_mismatch_c88db510-0a7e-4520-a085-8381f4278288-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] found [0] hits 
Dec 24 17:10:58: [2017-12-24T17:10:58,719][DEBUG][o.e.x.w.i.s.ExecutableSimpleInput] [hPjV7-n] [fxCyOMU8STOiNqoLUtOQhQ_logstash_version_mismatch_c88db510-0a7e-4520-a085-8381f4278288-2017-12-24T17:10:58.707Z] found [0] hits
```

(I have no idea why it's complaining about Kibana and Logstash, I don't have them installed)

UPDATE 2: Using curl's `--head` parameter instead of `-X HEAD` makes it work. No idea why. Asking for verbose output yields this:

```
$ curl -v --head http://localhost:9200/85a9b708-e89d-11e7-887a-02420aff0008
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9200 (#0)
> HEAD /85a9b708-e89d-11e7-887a-02420aff0008 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9200
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 467
content-length: 467
```

Which is the expected response, and the command exits normally.

However, this never exits:

```
$ curl -v -X HEAD http://localhost:9200/85a9b708-e89d-11e7-887a-02420aff0008
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the 
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9200 (#0)
> HEAD /85a9b708-e89d-11e7-887a-02420aff0008 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9200
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 467
<
```

What's with that warning from the second command?

Comment: Do you see anything in the service/docker logs?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, stupidly enough, I had not yet enabled more verbose ES logs. After doing so, I see an exception there. I just updated my original post to include it.

Comment: The issue seems that `--head` or `-I` expects no data and quits when the headers arrive. ES for some reason doesn't end the response and it goes in timeout. Ideally ES should end the response

Comment: Well, I tried it with a couple of other HTTP clients (Postman and Insomnia) and they both worked without a problem, so I think it's curl's and Python's problem in the way they are handling. In fact, there's a 10 year old bug report in the curl project about this exact issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/694/ Now I just have to find out if it's the same problem with whatever Python HTTP library ES is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in the elasticsearch==5.4.0 library I was using. Updating it to a newer version (5.5.1) fixed the issue.